# Excel: give names of cells if condition is met

Tags: excel

Imagine there is the following table in Excel. How do I get a list of non empty cells in a row.
Ideally This would be a given cell Name like here with 'Honey' ect. but I would settle for a list with the Excel cell Names i.e. B,D,G.
It is fairly easy to count the number of cells >0 but how to get their identity

```
recipe No   Honey   Sugar   Chocolate   Berries Juice   Milk     Result
        1       5       0           2         0     0      3     Honey,Chocolate,Milk
```

Comment: It's a frequent problem to concatenate a variable count of strings to a single one. It is nearly not possible with 'native' Excel formulas. You'd need VBA.

Comment: I'd do it in perl if only I knew how. The actual language or format is no a constraint

Answer (score 0):

You can use this VBA function. Call it by passing the line (range) with headers (ingredients) as first parameter and the line (range) with amounts (of whatever) as second. You can use this function like a native Excel function after putting it in a VBA module. (It doesn't checks for correct input here, so both ranges (headers and amounts) have to contain the equal count of cells)

```
Function Ingredients(headers As Range, counts As Range) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim s As String
    Dim sp As String

    For i = 1 To headers.Cells.Count
        If counts(i) <> 0 Then
            s = s + sp + headers(i)
            sp = ", "
        End If
    Next
    Ingredients = s
End Function
```

As example: (if ingredients are in columns B-G)

```
=Ingredients(B1:G1;B2:G2)
```